# is there any version of ubuntu that does not have snapd installed?

Tags: server, 18.04

I want to create a minimal containerhost for lxd on ubuntu 18.04 without having the snapd daemon at all.

Is there any version of ubuntu that comes without it?

Answer (score 4):

You can get the smallest installer - **Ubuntu Netboot Image**
from http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/netboot/  (LTS is recommended)
and then install all needed stuff
from it using  `tasksel` or regular `apt` / `apt-get`.

If you already have Ubuntu installed, then remove `snapd` as simple as

```
sudo apt-get purge snapd
```